# PowerPC protected/privileged mode structure

Tags: powerpc

Where can I get information on the privileged/protected mode structure of PowerPC?
I have tried seeing the user manuals but I couldn't get any info.

Answer (score 1):

Architecturally, it's fairly straightforward - as a broad overview: Firstly, you have a couple of bits in the Machine State Register (MSR): Problem state (PR) and Hypervisor (HV). Those two bits represent three states:

- PR=1, HV=x - unprivileged (typically: userspace)
- PR=0, HV=0 - supervisor (typically: virtualised guest OS kernel)
- PR=0, HV=1 - hypervisor (typically: hypervisor host, or non-virtualised OS kernel)

If your implementation doesn't support hardware virtualisation (ie., doesn't have a HV bit), then there are just two states:

- PR=1 - userspace
- PR=0 - supervisor

Then, certain facilities are only available at specific machine states. For example, some special purpose registers can only be accessed in PR=0 state; attempts to access these registers with PR=1 will cause a program interrupt, transferring control back to the OS. The OS can then decide what action to take (say, kill the process, or access the privileged resource on behalf of that process).

Of course, the MSR itself is privileged; userspace processes can't simply clear the PR bit to enter supervisor state.

For implementing access control to memory, the storage control facility can mark mappings as only available when the machine is in PR=0 and/or HV=1 states. Processing a virtual address translation will check the mapping configuration against the machine state, and potentially raise a data or instruction storage exception if access should not be allowed. Again, this transfers control back to the OS/hypervisor.

For details, see the POWER ISA documents. Book III has most of the details about privileged states.